# Is it bad practice to check Mongoose ReadyState before processing any request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have noticed that if I stop the MongoDb Service whilst my app is running, my app detects that it has been disconnected from the db, but does nothing to prevent requests from happening.
If I make a request it will eventually come back as a request timeout.

I was thinking of adding this bit of code to ensure that requests get a 'handled' response if the db connection is down.

```
app.use((res, req, next) => {
  console.log('MongoDb ReadyState: ', mongoose.connection.readyState);
  // if readyState is not 1 then alert user or return error.
  next();
})
```

My `mongoose.js` file which handles the MongoDb Connection:

```
/* This file will handle connection logic to the MongoDB database. */

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config');

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('connecting', () => {
  console.log('  Connecting to MongoDB...')
});

db.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('  Connected to MongoDB successfully!')
});

db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('  MongoDB connection opened!');
});

db.on('disconnected', () => {
  console.log('====================================================================');
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB lost!')
  console.log('====================================================================');
});

db.on('reconnected', () => {
  console.log('====================================================================');
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB re-established successfully!');
  console.log('====================================================================');
});

db.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  mongoose.disconnect();
});

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${config.mongoDB.URL}:${config.mongoDB.port}/${config.mongoDB.database}`, { useNewUrlParser: true })


module.exports = {
  mongoose
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say - yes, that is cumbersome to check for that in every request.
You could instead export from mongoose.js `connectMongo` function:

```
const connectMongo = () => mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${config.mongoDB.URL}:${config.mongoDB.port}/${config.mongoDB.database}`, { useNewUrlParser: true });


module.exports = {
  mongoose,
  connectMongo,
};
```

And await for it before starting the server to listen for the requests:

```
await connectMongo();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started on port 3000"));
```

---

If you'd like to react to Mongo connection issues you can add an event listener that will kill the app completely:

```
const handleDisconnect = () => process.exit(1);

mongoose.connection.on('error', handleDisconnect);
```

And (if you you have one) auto scaling will spin up new instance of your server and it will try to reconnect to MongoDB.

Comment: Hi Pavel, I am actually already waiting for mongo to establish  connection before I proceed with my server. My worry is that if the MongoService crashes or is turned of, then all my requests will still be attempted, but they will timeout as Mongo is inaccessible at that time.
Checking for the readyState before allowing a request to go through, will prevent that.

Comment: Hi @AdrianConstantinescu, I've updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have auto scaling so I was hoping to keep the app alive in the chance that MongoDb will re-connect at some point and not have to kill the app. In the meantime I'd just refuse any request and return an errorCode and an errorMessage.